# What does the linux operator $ do?

Tags: linux, terminal

I've seen many examples where $USER and similar commands are used but I could never figure out what it meant.
Whenever I search $ on Google, it doesn't recognise the symbol.

Comment: You can check this thread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-dollarsign-prefixed-string-in-a-script

Comment: There is no single Linux operator `$`. There are a lot of tools and contexts where `$` means different things. You will have to look them up individually. In your case, `$USER` is bourne shell syntax for expanding a variable by name. This is different from Bourne shell `$(...)` which expands a command, or from grep `foo$` where it anchors an expression, or from GNU as `mov $0, %rax` where it signifies a constant value.

Comment: @thatotherguy.  `mov $0, %rax` is not GNU-specific.   It is an AMD64 instruction written in AT&T assembler syntax.

Answer (score 0):

it is used to access system variable.

for example:
if you type in linux and/or unix shell

```
...$ my_var="some value"
...$ echo my_var
```

will print "some value"

```
...$ echo $USER
```

will print the name of shell user

```
...$ echo $?
```

will print the result of the previous command when successfully will print 0
in other word the result of "exit (num)" of you shell.

"$" also can indicate you are logged as no-root user for some shells the root will be indicated "#"

Answer (score 0):

The `$` is a special character that tells the shell interpreter to interpret the contents following as a value for a variable. It is also called variable substitution.

In the case of commands or command output, it can be used to call a shell command and store it's output as a variable's value. For example:

`VAR_1="$(ip link show)"`

Calling the variable `VAR_1` will print the output of the command `ip link show`.
This is called command substitution.

You can find out more information on special characters [Here](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html)
as well as information on wildcards, keywords and more.